# if statement with boolean within loop: 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, boolean, binance

I've been searching on stackoverflow and find many posts talking about the error, I've tried many of the solutions presented but none work. The problem looks so simple, I'm really confused what's wrong.

I do an API call to Binance, the output is a long dictionary. I get the key that interests me and it returns either True or False. When i test for type, it shows it's a boolean. I simply run a loop for different symbols in a list and test if the value is true, if so append the symbol name to a new list

```
test = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ATXETH', 'BATETH']
tickers = []
for x in test:
    info = client.get_symbol_info(x)
    a = info['isMarginTradingAllowed']
    if a:
        tickers.append(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help greatly appreciated. here is the output of info

```
 {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
 'status': 'TRADING',
 'baseAsset': 'BTC',
 'baseAssetPrecision': 8,
 'quoteAsset': 'USDT',
 'quotePrecision': 8,
 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8,
 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8,
 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT',
  'LIMIT_MAKER',
  'MARKET',
  'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT',
  'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'],
 'icebergAllowed': True,
 'ocoAllowed': True,
 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True,
 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True,
 'isMarginTradingAllowed': True}
```

Comment: `client.get_symbol_info(x)` is `None` for at least one `x` taken from `test`. Have you checked if this API call is successful for all the inputs you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in info variable, is None for one x in test list

This check fix the problem:

```
test = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ATXETH', 'BATETH']
tickers = []
for x in test:
    info = client.get_symbol_info(x)
    if info is None: continue
    a = info['isMarginTradingAllowed']
    if a:
        tickers.append(x)
```